# Why can't tls1.2 server use certificate's private key to encrypt 'server finish', and send if after 'server hello'?

Tags: tls, authentication

If don't consider 'change cipher spec' and performance. So client can send data immediately after 'client finish'.

The handshake process may look like this:

---

client hello ->

server hello <-

server cert <-

other server msg <-

server finished <- ***sign it (<strike>encrypt</strike>) use certificate private key***

client key exchange ->

client finished ->

application data -> ***send application data in 1rtt***

---

Comment: You can't encrypt with a private key.

Comment: @MechMK1 You're right. But server finished only contains the information used to verify the integrity. Signing with the private key can also verify the integrity of the message. I will change the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Server Finished message does not contain anything relevant. It's merely a test/validation to ensure the Server has generated proper Session Keys.

By encrypting a hash of the transcript of the handshake and sending it to the Client, the Client is able to validate that the Server has the correct Session Keys, and that both the Client and Server "saw" the same handshake records.

The Client does the same in the opposite direction with the Client Finished.

If you changed this mechanism, you'd need to add *another* mechanism to validate the Server has the proper session keys.

And, having the Server encrypt it's Certificate record to the Client would only serve one purpose:  Proves the Server has the matching Private Key... but that is already proven because the Server signs it's Server Key Exchange record.

So in the end, your suggestion would take away a necessary step, and add an unnecessary step.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood what I meant, or I did not fully understand your answer. I added a flow chart according to my meaning. Use server private key to encrypt the server finish instead of the cert.

Comment: @Karl It seems the intent of your suggestion is to reduce the RTT to 1. If so, I'd point you towards reading about TLS 1.3, which has deceased the handshake to only require 1 RTT. But not exactly in the way you have suggested.  Either way, in the TLS 1.2 and prior handshake, the Server Finished serves a specific function, and that function would be lost if it occurred where you suggested earlier in the handshake.